# Why won't boto3's FilterExpression accept more than 1 expression?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I am really baffled as to what I am doing wrong. It seems like the request I am making to the boto3 dynamodb client is perfect from what I can tell, but I am still not getting any results when I run the query. I suspect it's something to do with the FilterExpression, but I can't fathom it.

I am using a zappa/flask combo to build a web app, and I'm using dynamodb as the database. My AWS credentials and permissions are fine--I know that because I can run simpler queries just fine. Beyond that, the wider context of the application isn't relevant to my question.

I am running the following commands within the context of an object:

```
args = {... see below ...}
self.db = boto3.client('dynamodb')
self.db.query(**args)
```

Below is the args argument that I send to the client:

```
{"TableName": "clients", 
"IndexName": "client_id", 
"FilterExpression": "#filattr0 < :filattrval0 AND #filattr1 = :filattrval1", 
"KeyConditionExpression": "#keyindexattr0 = :keyindexvalue0", 
"ExpressionAttributeNames": {
    "#filattr0": "time", 
    "#filattr1": "status", 
    "#keyindexattr0": "client_id"
},
"ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":filattrval0": {"N": "1542696080"},
    ":filattrval1": {"S": "pending"},
    ":keyindexvalue0": {"S": "00000000-0000-0000-000000000000"}
},
"Limit": 100,
"ConsistentRead": false,
"Select": "ALL_ATTRIBUTES"}
```

The response I get back from this query is the following:

```
{'Items': [], 
'Count': 0, 
'ScannedCount': 8, 
'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '*blahblahblah*', 
'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 
'HTTPHeaders': {
    'server': 'Server', 
    'date': 'Tue, 20 Nov 2018 06:41:20 GMT', 
    'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 
    'content-length': '39', 
    'connection': 'keep-alive', 
    'x-amzn-requestid': '*blahblahblah*',
    'x-amz-crc32': '*numbers*'},
    'RetryAttempts': 0
}}
```

Now, I am looking at the dynamodb table through my AWS Console, and it is showing me the following object in the appropriate table. In fact, when I construct this query in the table view of the dynamodb console on the AWS Website, it returns the following object, so I know the parameters are acceptable to AWS:

```
# Taken from the JSON view of the item in the database
# I removed the UUIDs just in case...
{
    "client_id": "00000000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "modify_date": "1542637150",
    "schedule_id": "00000000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "software_version": "0.1",
    "status": "pending",
    "template_id": "00000000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "time": "1542646800",
    "timezone": "PDT"
}
```

The weirdest thing is that when I run the query using the following args variable:

```
{'TableName': 'hmcmSchedule', 
'IndexName': 'client_id', 
'FilterExpression': '#filattr0 = :filattrval0', 
'KeyConditionExpression': '#keyindexattr0 = :keyindexvalue0',
'ExpressionAttributeNames': {
    '#filattr0': 'status', 
    '#keyindexattr0': 'client_id'
}, 
'ExpressionAttributeValues': {
    ':filattrval0': {'S': 'pending'},
    ':keyindexvalue0': {'S': '00000000-0000-0000-000000000000'}
}, 
'Limit': 100, 
'ConsistentRead': False, 
'Select': 'ALL_ATTRIBUTES'}
```

I get the following response from the database:

```
# UUIDs have once again been removed, just in case...
{'Items': [{
    'modify_date': {'S': '1542637150'}, 
    'template_id': {'S': '00000000-0000-0000-000000000000'}, 
    'software_version': {'S': '0.1'}, 
    'client_id': {'S': '00000000-0000-0000-000000000000'}, 
    'status': {'S': 'pending'}, 
    'timezone': {'S': 'PDT'}, 
    'time': {'S': '1542646800'}, 
    'schedule_id': {'S': '00000000-0000-0000-000000000000'}
}], 
'Count': 1, 
'ScannedCount': 8, 
'ResponseMetadata': {
    'RequestId': '*blahblahblah*', 
    'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 
    'HTTPHeaders': {
        'server': 'Server', 
        'date': 'Tue, 20 Nov 2018 07:55:59 GMT', 
        'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 
        'content-length': '348', 
        'connection': 'keep-alive', 
        'x-amzn-requestid': '*blahblahblah*', 
        'x-amz-crc32': '1922642857'
    }, 
    'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

What is it about my FilterExpression that is keeping this from working? I've been examining it for hours, and can't see the forest for the trees. I read the documentation extensively, and I think i've covered everything.

Any help or insight anybody could offer would b greatly appreciated...

Comment: IMHO, the best place for database related question is https://dba.stackexchange.com/  . BTW, this is not a boto3 question.

Comment: According to the output of the successful query, it *looks like* `time` wasn't stored as a number, but as a string: `'time': {'S': '1542646800'},`  I might be wrong but comparing this to a number seems problematic.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I don't think it's that time was stored as a string, as the datatype in the database is number. It is odd that it was returned as a string, but the documentation did say that dynamodb sends and receives all values as strings. So it may just be a quirk of the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, @Michael-sqlbot was right. The issue turned out to be a combination of problems that I just didn't pick up on. I had everything correct but the portion where I was specifying the ExpressionAttributeValues:

So this:

```
"ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":filattrval0": {"N": "1542696080"},
    ":filattrval1": {"S": "pending"},
    ":keyindexvalue0": {"S": "00000000-0000-0000-000000000000"}
},
```

Was entirely correct. The problems I kept having were that I would switch databases without switching attributes, the parameters I set didn't match anything in the database, or--as @Michael-sqlbot pointed out--the value of time stored in the database was of a different datatype.

You can't compare a number against a string, as it turns out. And since I was debugging from Zappa tail --since 5m, I often wound up looking at the wrong material.

So I was right, the code does work, i'm not insane, and I shouldn't code when i'm really tired.